# Android error when BT is connect

Tags: android

I am a begginer in Android. I am a PLC programmer, but I would like to write application for my mobile phone. I would like to remote control RGB led via Arduino. But when I make any changes I have the error, and I don't know what is this.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.led.led, PID: 7790
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.led.led/com.led.led.ledControl}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at com.led.led.ledControl.onCreate(ledControl.java:121)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Put your some code where the got error...

Comment: This is link to my all project

http://www.uschovna.cz/zasilka/LIYG3TSCYWN5IA3G-BZZ/ 

I am sorry for my crazy program, I am begginer.
 thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException occurs when you try to access something not yet defined.
Like for eg. trying to setText in a textview before assigning it in the activity with the id in the xml.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, and how can i find where is a problem in definition?

Comment: I find a calling function witouh declaration. Thank you very much. The problem is solved.

Comment: You are welcome. :)